# How to change the shape of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchical-clustering

I have a one column pandas dataframe of the shape (44,1), and would like to change it to (44,). How can I do that?

I want to convert a pandas.DataFrame to a pandas.Series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

```
#Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':[1,2,3,4,5]})

#Shape of a single-column dataframe
df.shape
#Output: (5, 1)

#Shape of series
df['val'].shape
#Output: (5,)
```